# TypeError: Object of type Cursor is not JSON serializable when comparing request.form.get and db value

Tags: python, mysql, flask, jinja2

I am pograming a simple web app with flask and am trying to implement a login process. My /register seems to work fine with username and hashed pwd being correctly inserted in my database when registering. However, when it comes to the login part I can't seem to be comparing the username stored in MySQL and the one from resquest.form.get, I get the following error message : TypeError: Object of type Cursor is not JSON serializable.

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    
    db = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    c = db.cursor()

    if request.method== "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        pwd_hash = sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            flash("must provide username", "error")
            return redirect("/login")

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            flash("must provide password", "error")
            return redirect("/login")

        # Query database for username
        if (c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=:username", {"username" : username}).fetchall()[0][0] == 0):
            flash("invalid username", "error")
            return redirect("/login")
        
        if (c.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE(username=:username)", {"username": username}).fetchall()[0][0] != pwd_hash):
            flash("invalid password", "error")
            return redirect("/login")
        
        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = c.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE(:username=:username)", {"username": username})

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Please post the full backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't fetch the row here:

```
session["user_id"] = c.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE(:username=:username)", {"username": username})
```

`c.execute()` returns the cursor object, you can't put that into a session variable. It should be

```
session["user_id"] = c.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE(:username=:username)", {"username": username}).fetchone()[0]
```

But there doesn't seem to be a reason to do another query here. It's just going to return the same username that's in the parameter. So just write

```
sesion["user_id"] = username
```

BTW, it's generally considered poor security design to distinguish invalid usernames from invalid passwords. Just do a single query with both the username and password. If it fails, report "Invalid username or password".

```
        if (c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password", {"username" : username, "password": pwd_hash}).fetchone()[0] == 0):
            flash("invalid username or password", "error")
            return redirect("/login")
```

Other issues:

1. You're assigning variables from the `request.form` parameters before you check that they were actually filled in.
2. If you only need one row, use `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice on improvements (I am still a beginner), the problem seemed to have been related to the non definition of the session["user_id"], corrected it and it seemed to work fine. Thanks again !

Comment: No, the problem was related to not calling `fetchone()` or `fetchall()`.